# Different Backgrounds for title page and rest of the document (Koma Book)

Tags: backgrounds

I use something like

```
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{%
  firstpage=true,
  contents={First Page}, 
  placement=center
}
```

which sets the contents on the title page.

I now would like to add a (different) background on every following page.

Any ideas?

Comment: please show a complete example. That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: For a single page, one can use a tikzpicture.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0686#273885 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395530/make-tikz-nodes-flush-with-slide-edges-in-beamer-title-slide/395544?r=SearchResults&s=2|15.0451#395544 for example.

Comment: Is the background some image file or some text you want to place? If it is not already a Ti*k*Z picture and you don't need to create a Ti*k*Z picture (so just some more or less ordinary contents) you could use `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(<coordinate>){<stuff>}}` (see the [`ltshipout` documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/ltshipout-doc/0)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
   \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,emptypage}
\usepackage[placement=center]{background}
\author{Author of Myself}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \backgroundsetup{contents=Confidential,color=yellow}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \Huge   Back\par
        \vspace{2cm}
        \Large Author of Myself
        \normalsize
        \vfill
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{RSEdizioni.png}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
    \backgroundsetup{contents=}
    \mainmatter
    \backgroundsetup{contents=To review,color=blue!30}
    \lipsum[1-25]   
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work on the title page.

Comment: I added a new version that works also for title page.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way around it.

I use the background package for the title page and the draftwatermark
package for the rest.

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Maybe, you can add a code example that shows how to do this?